# TSQL = ALL Predicate not returning rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is a schema and query of a bigger problem I am trying to figure out. I would have expected the below to return one row but it returns none. OK the eval is returning false but why???

```
declare @PCM TABLE
(
  ProductId int,
  CategoryId int
)
INSERT @PCM VALUES(68,158)
INSERT @PCM VALUES(68,113)
INSERT @PCM VALUES(68,138)
INSERT @PCM VALUES(68,161)
INSERT @PCM VALUES(70,158)
INSERT @PCM VALUES(70,273)

declare @ProdFltr TABLE
(
 CategoryId int
)
INSERT @ProdFltr VALUES(158)
INSERT @ProdFltr VALUES(113)

SELECT P.ProductId FROM @PCM P WHERE P.CategoryId = ALL(SELECT CategoryId FROM @ProdFltr)
```

OK I think I was mis-reading the MSDN docs as this works exactly as I would expect. Use this instead of the above for the ProdFltr

```
declare @ProdFltr TABLE
(
 CategoryId int,
 CategoryId2 int
)

INSERT @ProdFltr VALUES(158,113)
```

So the ALL can only deal with one row from the subquery??

@acfrancis and Amirreza Keshavarz your answers filled in the gap thank you VERY much. So how would I get JUST the pcm records that matched EVERYTHING in the ProdFltr?

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use ``ALL``? Have you tried using ``P.CategoryId IN (SELECT...``? That should return two rows with the same value. You can then reduce it to a single row by adding a ``DISTINCT`` to the outer select.

Comment: NO!! I don't have to use ALL. My concern though is that EVERY!! row match. So if I added INSERT @PCM(70,113) INSERT @PCM(70,237) I don't want to see 70 in my results. With IN I get 70. I've added these to the schema above for others.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to select the ProductId in ``@PCM`` only if there is a row in ``@PCM`` with that ProductId for each CategoryId in ``@ProdFltr``. If so, that requires a different select altogether.

Comment: Let me restate just to make sure typos vs confusion. I want to select only the prodid from pcm where the pcm.categoryid matches EVERY row in ProdFltr.CategoryId......so in the schema above id 70 should not return as it only matches ONE of the rows in ProdFltr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALL` will always be false in your scenario because for each individual row of @PCM, the CategoryId column can't be equal to all the CategoryId values (all the rows) in @ProdFltr. The only way it would be true is if @ProdFltr had all of its rows with the same value for CategoryId.

EDIT:
With the new information in the comments, I think you want a select like this:

```
SELECT P.ProductId 
FROM @PCM P 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM @ProdFltr PF
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM @PCM P2
                                    WHERE P2.ProductId = P.ProductId
                                          AND P2.CategoryId = PF.CategoryId))
```

In other words, select the ProductId if there isn't a row in @ProdFltr that isn't matched by a row in @PCM for the same ProductId.

You might still add a DISTINCT on the outermost select if you don't want repeated ProductIds.

Answer (score 1):

ALL requires the scalar_expression to compare positively to every value that is returned by the subquery. For instance, if the subquery returns values of 2 and 3, scalar_expression <= ALL (subquery) would evaluate as TRUE for a scalar_expression of 2. If the subquery returns values of 2 and 3, scalar_expression = ALL (subquery) would evaluate as FALSE, because some of the values of the subquery (the value of 3) would not meet the criteria of the expression.
For statements that require the scalar_expression to compare positively to only one value that is returned by the subquery, see SOME | ANY (Transact-SQL).

From : [Msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx)